# Need Help: Python 2.7.13 Unit Conversions

Tags: python, python-2.7

The table below contains some lengths in terms of feet.

1 inch = .083333 foot; 1 rod = 16. 5 feet; 1 yard = 3.28155 feet; 1 furlong = 660 feet; 1 meter = 3.28155 feet; 1 kilometer = 3281.5 feet; 1 fathom = 6 feet; 1 mile = 5280 feet.

Write a program that displays the nine different units of measure; requests the unit to convert from, the unit to convert to, and the quantity to be converted; and then displays the converted quantity.

Use the file Units.txt to create a dictionary that provides the number of feet for a given unit of length.

The conversions.txt file reads:

inches, .083333; furlongs, 660; yards, 3; fathoms, 6; feet, 1; kilometers, 3281.5; meters, 3.2815; miles, 5280; rods, 16.5

```
print 'UNITS OF LENGTH'
print 'Inches',     'furlongs',     'yards'
print 'rods',       'miles',        'fathoms'
print 'meters',     'kilometers',   'feet'

conversions = {}
with open('Units.txt') as fname:
    for line in fname:
        (keys, values) = line.split(',')
        conversions[keys] = float(values)
def convert(from_unit, to_unit, values):
    from__unit1 = conversions[from_unit1]
    to__unit2 = conversions[to_unit2]

new_values = values * (from__unit1 / to__unit2)

return str(new_value) + to__unit2

unit1 = raw_input('Units to convert from: ')
unit2 = raw_input('Units to convert to: ')
num1 = raw_input('Enter your value: ')

print(convert(unit1, unit2, (num1)))
```

Comment: whats wrong with it?

Comment: Ive had multiple problems and I am new to coding, but when I run it as of now it says NameError: global name 'from_unit1' is not defined

Comment: I'll help you out.

Comment: thanks a lot... anything helps, I've just been stuck working on this problem for awhile

Comment: @john: If your problem has been solved, please don't replace your entire question with just the solution.  For one thing, it makes the thread impossible to follow for any future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking at your comment above. The reason its saying "NameError: global name 'from_unit1'" is because there has been no from_unit1 variable defined yet.

I assume you meant to access the convert() methods parameters, from_unit and to_unit? So it might look like this:

```
def convert(from_unit, to_unit, values):
    from__unit1 = conversions[from_unit]
    from__unit2 = conversions[to_unit]
```

The variables used inside the function must match the passed in arguement or must be declared somewhere in the file. If declared in the file outside the function, for Python 2x you will need to put "global variable_name" without quotes at the start of your function

Edit:

The next thing I would do is put these two lines inside convert():

```
new_values = values * (from__unit1 / to__unit2)
return str(new_value) + to__unit2
```

Reason being is that the two variables from_unit1 and to__unit2 cannot be accessed outside of the function. They were created inside the function and once a function completes all its steps, the variables will disappear.

So the function should look something like this:

```
def convert(from_unit, to_unit, values):
    from__unit1 = conversions[from_unit]
    from__unit2 = conversions[to_unit]
    new_values = values * (from__unit1 / to__unit2)
    return str(new_value) + to__unit2
```

I believe that should print the desired result. Let us know :)

Comment: yep, that's what I was going to say.

Comment: Thank you, the firs part worked but when I add the second part.. it readsline 22, in <module>
    print(convert(unit1, unit2, float(num1)))   line 16, in convert
    return str(new_value) + to__unit2
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects

Comment: Not sure if you know what concatenation is but ill explain briefly, its just adding two strings together using the + operator. So youre just receiving an error because the two things youre concatenating are not both strings.

In your return line only one variable has been converted using the str() function. You just need to do the same to the other variable. Keep in mind, there won't be a space in between the printed results

Comment: no worries, to avoid getting down voted I think it might be a good idea to post your error in the main post :) Just like @thesonyman101 asked because its hard to know right away.